# Jinja2 access a list of dict in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

Hey all any idea how to access a list of dict ?

In Flask:

```
users = [{
    'username': 'john',
    'city': 'Toronto'
},
{
    'username': 'James',
    'city': 'Montreal'
}]

return render_template('home.html', users=users)
```

and in my template

```
<script>
    var users = {{users}}
</script>
```

All I get is

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply [`toJson`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/templating/#standard-filters) filter to make valid javascript object.

```
<script>
    var users = {{users | tojson | safe}}
</script>
```